# Implement http interceptor in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having RestCall service in my Project.I am using $http.get to fetch data from backend. I want to display loading image until i get data .How to do this by using interceptor.

Comment: Easy: implement 2 interceptors, `request` and `response`. Set loading flag on say $rootScope in request and unset in response.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: in config inject $httpProvider

```
.config(function($httpProvider...............
```

Step 2: follow sample

```
.config(function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($rootScope){
        return {
            request: function(config){
                //Show loading  
                return config ;  
            },
            requestError: function(response){
                //Hide loading
                return response;
            },
            response: function(response){
                //Hide loading
                return response;
            },
            responseError: function(response){
                //Hide loadig
                return response;
            }
        };
    });
})
```